# how to use Hover inside a Mouseover event

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I am trying to create a **drag and drop function** for my website **without** using `jQuery UI` or the HTML5 drag drop functions. I have **figured out the drag part** but I am **unable to drop them** in specific drop areas. here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<ul id="grid">
     <li class="drop">
          <div class="drag" id="el_1"><div>
     </li>
     <li class="drop">
          <div class="drag" id="el_2"><div>
     </li>
     <li class="drop">
          <div class="drag" id="el_3"><div>
     </li>
     <li class="drop"></li>
     <li class="drop"></li>
     <li class="drop"></li>
</ul>
<script>
     $(function() {
          $('.handle').mousedown(drag_and_drop);
     });
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
#grid{
     position:relative;
     width:360px;
     height:auto;
}
.drop{
     width:100px;
     height:100px;
     margin:10px;
}
.drag{
     position:absolute;
     width:100px;
     height:100px;
}
#el_1{ top:10px; left:10px}
#el_2{ top:10px; left:130px}
#el_3{ top:10px; left:250px}
```

**SCRIPT**

```
function drag_and_drop(e){
        var drag = $(this);
        var drop = drag.parent();

        drag.addClass('draggable');

        drag_h = drag.outerHeight(),
        drag_w = drag.outerWidth(),
        pos_y = drag.offset().top + drag_h - e.pageY,
        pos_x = drag.offset().left + drag_w - e.pageX;

        $('.draggable').css('z-index', 9000).mousemove(function(e) {

/*

IN THIS MOUSEMOVE FUNCTION IS THERE ANY WAY TO DETECT IF THE DRAGGABLE DIV IS "HOVERING" OVER THE li.drop ELEMENTS?

*/

            $('.draggable').offset({
                top: e.pageY + pos_y - drag_h,
                left: e.pageX + pos_x - drag_w

            }); 
        }).mouseup(function() {
            drag.removeClass('draggable');
        });   
    e.preventDefault(); // stops the browser default drag method    
};
```

Is there any way that once I have started to drag an object that it can detect if it is over a specific li.drop - from which I will be able to drop it into?

Comment: I should also note that once a drop takes place I will be moving the <div class="drop"> into the coorisponding <li class="drop"> and I will be saving the changes in a database but that is beyond the scope of my question. Just in case you want to know why my html is set up this way

Comment: You really shouldn't be assigning a mouseup handler inside of the mousemove handler. You're going to gobble up memory like nobody's business.

Comment: Shmiddty - thanks, I removed that piece of code

Comment: You're also binding additional `mousemove` and `mouseup` handlers to `.draggable` each time you `mousedown` a `.handle`. You should probably `$(this).off("mousemove mouseup")` inside of your `mouseup` handler, or change your code to only bind these handlers once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use the below to get the current mouse position and write another function to see if that position is within a droppable divs bounds. good article here:

http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position#How_do_I_find_the_mouse_position.3F